# Allow my OpenVPN server to work behind a Cisco 800 Router

Tags: cisco, openvpn, ios

I have an OpenVPN Ubuntu Server working on ip 192.168.1.11

I need to let my roadwarriors use it from anywhere.
I have a Cisco 800 router but I'm not an expert...
I've downloaded using tftp its running config

```
copy running-config tftp
```

and I'm editing it with notepad++

I think that I should add:

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.11 1194 mypublicip 1194 extendable
```

is this all?
Then I should just restore this modified config and I'm done?
Should I also add a permissive rule on the firewall config (always cisco 800)?

Cisco manuals suggest me to delete all rows in my config contaning "AAA" I just have: no aaa new-model should I keep it? 
I'm reading that those "aaa" commands could lock me out of the router :/

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to say "udp" instead of "tcp", unless you have a non-standard OpenVPN configuration.  OpenVPN, by default, will use udp.

Comment: Why not configure the Cisco 800 to be the VPN endpoint instead of OpenVPN?

Comment: Great suggestion, cjc! I'm doing it right away...

Tom if I could do that I wouldn't be asking such a "simple" question.
Your idea is good anyway: I'll check how to do that :)

Comment: ps Cisco manuals suggest me to delete all rows in my config contaning "AAA" I just have: no aaa new-model
should I keep it?

Comment: I'm reading horrible things about this aaa command: maybe it could lock me out of the router :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`no aaa new-model` is fine if you don't have any dialin or vpn configured on this router.

Regarding your NAT/PAT issue, your statement should be OK if you are indeed using openvpn over TCP.

The other solution would be to set up a static nat redirection for all ports (what consumer routers call 'DMZ'):

```
Router(config)#ip nat inside source static 192.168.1.11 <publicIp>
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to delete this no aaa new-model row just to be sure?

Comment: I've tried my config but it is not working, probably because I neet to implement also a firewall rule...

Comment: @Pitto: deleting `no aaa new-model` means configuring AAA by typing `aaa new-model`. This can work, but can be difficult to set up for someone without cisco knowledge.

Comment: @Pitto: firewall rule? Why would you want that? Is the NAT (or PAT) already working outbound on the Cisco for other clients?

Comment: Firewall router was really useless: you're right...
The config is working perfectly now :)
I just had problems because I thought that checking cisco's ports with nmap would've given me data about port 1194 but it didn't so I assumed it was not working (even if it was :) )